# How to get a number from a html source page?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to retrieve the followed by count on my instagram page. I can't seem  to get the Regex right and would very much appreciate some help.

Here's what I'm looking for:

```
y":{"count":
```

That's the beginning of the string, and I want the 4 numbers after that.

```
$string = preg_replace("{y"\"count":([0-9]+)\}","",$code);
```

Someone suggested this ^ but I can't get the formatting right...

Comment: Any reason for not using the [api](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)?

Comment: I'm trying to practice my regex

Comment: What I'm looking for begins with 'y":{"count' and I need 4 numbers after that. Any ideas what the regex below isn't working?

    $string = preg_replace(/^y":{"count[0-9]/","",$code);

Comment: `{4}` is for 4 of the previous character. You should look at a tutorial on ranges and quantifiers. The `{` in your regex should be escaped as well.

Comment: Your `preg_replace` usage is also incorrect, parameter 1 is regex, 2 is replace value, 3 is string/haystack. I'm not sure what you are trying to do there. You probably want `preg_match` though. Can you post a sample string.

Comment: @chris85 Yea just did!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>You haven't posted your strings so it is a guess to what the regex should be... so I'll answer on why your codes fail.</s>

```
preg_replace('"followed_by":{"count":\d')
```

This is very far from the correct `preg_replace` usage. You need to give it the replacement string and the string to search on. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Your second usage:

```
$string = preg_replace(/^y":{"count[0-9]/","",$code);
```

Is closer but `preg_replace` is global so this is searching your whole file (or it would if not for the anchor) and will replace the found value with nothing. What your really want (I think) is to use `preg_match`.

```
$string = preg_match('/y":\{"count(\d{4})/"', $code, $match);
$counted = $match[1];
```

This presumes your regex was kind of correct already.

Per your update:

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/aR2iU2/1

```
$code = 'y":{"count:1234';
$string = preg_match('/y":\{"count:(\d{4})/', $code, $match);
$counted = $match[1];
echo $counted;
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/489436

I removed the `^` which requires the regex starts at the start of your string, escaped the `{` and made the`\d` be 4 characters long. The `()` is a capture group and stores whatever is found inside of it, in this case the 4 numbers.

Also if this isn't just for learning you should be prepared for this to stop working at some point as the service provider may change the format. The API is a safer route to go.

Comment: Yea, I'm mostly trying to learn regex. You nailed it. Thank you for explaining all the elements of regex in your description man. Much appreciated :)

Comment: Good luck with the learning, I recommend working with regex101.com, it lets you test the regex and gives explanations. Also take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info and http://www.rexegg.com/. Also a final note look at modifiers, http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php, that can affect why a regex does/doesn't work for you as well.

Comment: Hey @chris85 hope you get this. I've been working on this one escape for the last hour.

 '(\d+)</b> views' 

This is my first argument in preg_match but it doesn't find anything. I think it has to do with the '</b>' I've tried every escape combination possible... Any ideas? When I remove the '</b>' it's able to find a number but not when it's there.

Comment: Can you post your actual regex, is it `/(\d+)</b> views/`? If so the `</b>` needs to be `<\/b>` because the `/` is your delimiter, http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php.

Answer (score 0):

This regexp should capture value you're looking for in the first group:

```
\{"count":([0-9]+)\}
```

Use it with `preg_match_all` function to easily capture what you want into array (you're using `preg_replace` which isn't for retrieving data but for... well replacing it).

Your regexp isn't working because you didn't escaped curly brackets. And also you didn't put count quantifier (plus sign in my example) so it would only capture first digit anyway.

Comment: Just tried this but I couldn't get the formatting right? Any thoughts?

Comment: @AnthraxBear what do you mean by "formatting"? What result did you got?